# How can I replace the letter 'a' from a string and replace it with two more a's recursively?

Tags: java, recursion

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddAs
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a word:");

        sc1.close();

        String n = ("aaa");

        char s = 'a';

        System.out.println(s2);

        String pp = moreAs(s2, s, n)

        System.out.println(pp);
    }

    public static String moreAs(String p, char s, String n, String s2)
    {
        if (p.length() < 1)
        {
            return p;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++)
        {
            if (p.charAt(i) == s)
            {
                p = p.substring(0, 1) + n + p.substring(++i)

                System.out.println(p);

                return moreAs(p, s, n)
            }
        }
    }

    return s2;
}
```

I'm writing a java program for work, the program must replace any occurrence of the letter 'a' with two more a'
For example if the user inputs "anagram" the output would be 
"aaanaaagraaam". This must be done recursively, any ideas?
I think i'm on the right track I'm not to sure, ask any questions. I do know I've a string called n which contains 3 a's but I thought If i removed one I have to replaced it with three a's.

Comment: You must have an unusual job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box) [String::replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function or by using your custom recursive function as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Original string: " + str);
        System.out.println("Updated string: " + str.replaceAll("a", "aaa"));

        // Using recursive function
        System.out.println("Updated string (using recursive function): " + moreAs(str, 0));
    }

    static String moreAs(String str, int n) {
        if (n == str.length()) {
            return str;
        }
        if (str.charAt(n) == 'a') {
            // Call the function recursively after replacing 'a' with 'aaa' in str 
            return moreAs(str.substring(0, n + 1) + "aa" + str.substring(n + 1), n + 3);
        } else {
            // Call the function recursively without changing str
            return moreAs(str, n + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a string: anagram
Original string: anagram
Updated string: aaanaaagraaam
Updated string (using recursive function): aaanaaagraaam
```

The logic in the custom recursive function is simple and straight forward. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is calling the same method again and again until you reach a termination condition.

So start by deciding a termination condition. We will be analyzing the string up char by char until there is none left, so a good termination condition here is the empty string. (Which is what you have already correctly done.)

Then we split the string to look at it one character at a time, the `head` character, the remainder of the string is the `tail`.

Depending on the head's content we either keep the char, or replace with `"aaa"`, but in both cases we recurse in to `replaceAwithAAA` with the tail.

As tail is shorter each time, this is guaranteed to get to the empty string and so finish at some point.

```
  public static String replaceAwithAAA(String s) {
    if (s.length() == 0) return ""; // termination condition

    char   head = s.charAt(0);
    String tail = s.substring(1);

    if (head == 'a') { // hint: this could also be `s.startsWith("a")`
      return "aaa" + replaceAwithAAA(tail); // recursion
    } else {
      return head  + replaceAwithAAA(tail); // recursion
    }
  }
```

I'm sure you can adjust your `moreAs` to more represent this structure. Having a `for` loop inside your method is a mistake, the looping is done on the call stack instead.

Answer (score 0):

Only two line of code you need

```
String s = "anagram";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("a","aaa"));
```

Which will print

```
aaanaaagraaam
```

Comment: I've replaced the code above and used and just used a loop, a .contains, an if statement and then your suggestion of .replaceAll. It won't return anything after I enter in  a word for some reason

Comment: why do want to check contains ?

Comment: Because they are also trying to use recursion in some way. OP, this is a complete solution, so you cannot shoe horn this in to a recursive one.

Comment: you don't need recursion at all, use regular expression it will solve all kind of patterns, this answer is based on the code you have provided